# Fit large text in canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am showing dynamic text on canvas using this code

```
DynamicLayout sl = new DynamicLayout(text, textPaint, rect.width(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1, 1, true);
        mCanvas.save();
        float textYCoordinate = rect.top + 50;
        float textXCoordinate = rect.left + 20;
        mCanvas.translate(textXCoordinate, textYCoordinate);

        sl.draw(mCanvas);
        mCanvas.restore();
```

but if the text is large, it goes below the screen. Also i am adjusting the textsize dynamically so if text size got large than also the text goes below the screen, so i am thinking about to split the text according to screen means adjust that much text on screen that it can handle and add the remaining text on next frame... but i don't know how to implement this code. Actually i am creating a book app and creating each page as a frame on every page flip. Can anyone please help me about this problem.

Comment: remove `+ 50` and `+ 20`, what do you need it for?

Comment: Can you show the whole code? Do you restore canvas after each drawing?

Comment: @pskink it doesn't matter

Comment: @Maciej yes i am restoring

Comment: what doesnt matter? you have the same result if you add 20, 200 or 2000? what do you want to achieve with those magic numbers?

Comment: @pskink Ok i have removed it but its not working...

Comment: @Itava can you show the whole class?

Comment: @pskink from those magic numbers i am just giving space from top and left of the screen, this is not related to what my problem is...

Comment: now if you want to check what part of your text is out of your `Canvas` use `android.text.Layout` API

Comment: @pskink can we scroll the text of this Dynamic layout

Comment: @pskink can you please show some code to check what part of text is out of Canvas using android.text.Layout API

Comment: @pskink how can i scroll a text in a canvas. Its not possible, i think

Comment: @pskink actually i am using this  (  https://github.com/eschao/android-PageFlip   )  library

Comment: `"can you please show some code to check what part of text is out of Canvas using android.text.Layout API"`, see `Layout#getLine*`methods then